# I want to remove everything contained in one list from another list along with the next line from another file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I want to remove everything contained in one list from another list along with the next line. For instance: 

list2.txt contains:

```
A
D
```

list1a.txt contains:

```
>A
 AAAAA
>B
 GGGGG
>C
 CCCC
>D
 TTTT
```

I expect the following output:

```
>B
GGGGG
>C
CCCC
```

Where >A and >D have been removed along with the lines below them.

I have tried:

```
input=$1
file_to_edit=$2
while IFS= read -r var
do
echo $var
sed "s/$var//g" $file_to_edit >f2.txt
done < "$input"
```

f2.txt returns:

```
>A
AAAAA
>B
GGGGG
>C
CCCC
>
TTTT
```

As expected it returns the "D" removed, but not the A, and not the line below them. 
I need to remove any line contained in the first list from
the second file, as well as the line below it.

Answer (score 2):

With `GNU sed`

```
$ sed 's|.*|/^>&$/,+1d|' f1
/^>A$/,+1d
/^>D$/,+1d
$ sed -f <(sed 's|.*|/^>&$/,+1d|' f1) f2
>B
 GGGGG
>C
 CCCC
```

- create command for each line, `+n` means n lines after the matching line
- then use those commands to act upon the other file

If `GNU sed` is not available, try

```
$ sed -f <(sed 's|.*|/^>&$/{N;d;}|' f1) f2
>B
 GGGGG
>C
 CCCC
```

- here `N` command is used to add next line to pattern space. Then they are deleted. For two more lines, use `N;N` for three use `N;N;N` and so on

With `awk` and [getline](https://web.archive.org/web/20170524214527/http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline)

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[">"$0]; next} ($0 in a) && (getline x)>0{next} 1' f1 f2
>B
 GGGGG
>C
 CCCC
```

If there will be only one match found in `f2`

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[">"$0];next} ($0 in a) && (getline x)>0{delete a[$0];next} 1' f1 f2
```

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you also in same.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]=$0;next} /^>/{c=$0;sub(/^>/,"",c)} (c in a){getline;next} 1' list2.txt list1a.txt
```

Output will be as follows.

```
>B
 GGGGG
>C
 CCCC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cp 2.txt /tmp/temp1
while read var
do
echo $var
sed 's,'"$var"',,g' /tmp/temp1 > /tmp/temp2
mv -f /tmp/temp2 /tmp/temp1
done < 1.txt
cp /tmp/temp1 3.txt
```

or

```
while read var
do
echo "s/"$var"//g" >> sed.script2
done < 1.txt
sed --file=sed.script2 2.txt > 3.txt
rm -f sed.script
```